# How can I adjust UITextView font size dynamically in CollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextview

I have a collectionView that includes a UITextView. I want to set font size of TextView dynamically. After my investigations I found below codes. It works fine for UITextView dynamic font size. If text is long, codes arrange the most suitable font size according to UITextView frame height.

But my problem is that when ViewController did load, UITextView font size in UICollectionViewCell doesn't change correctly. But When I swipe to another cell font size change correctly. And then I swipe again to first cell, font size sets correct font size.

So, when ViewController did load, UITextView font size in UICollectionViewCell(called QuoteCell) is 20pt but it must be 36pt. But I cannot set this size without swipe to another cell and to backward.

I tried to set font inside awakeFromNib and willDisplayCell or cellForRowAtIndexPath methods. I also tried to use setNeedDisplay but it didn't work.

What is the problem? What do I overlook?

```
// This codes adjust font size according to UITextView size.

extension UITextView {
func updateTextFont() {

    if (self.text.isEmpty || self.bounds.size.equalTo(CGSize.zero)) {
        print("Text Empty")
    }

    let textViewSize = self.frame.size
    let fixedWidth = textViewSize.width
    let expectSize = self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

    var expectFont = self.font
    if (expectSize.height > textViewSize.height) {

        while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height > textViewSize.height) {
            expectFont = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize - 1)
            self.font = expectFont
        }
    }
    else {
        while (self.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))).height < textViewSize.height) {

            expectFont = self.font!.withSize(self.font!.pointSize + 1)
            self.font = expectFont
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I set txtQuote text size in willDisplayCell method.(I tried this in cellForRowAtIndexPath and awakeFromNib methods.)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let quoteCell = cell as! QuoteCell

    quoteCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    quoteCell.txtQuote.updateTextFont()

}
```

Comment: you need to find out first textview hight according to text and font size then assign hight to collectionview cell height.

Comment: After setting height are you reloading the cell ?

Comment: @AtulParmar actually textView height is static (w:300, h:137) and updateTextFont method get this size initially. TextView font must change according to this height.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes.

Comment: @ismail you want set set font of text according to textview height (Fixed height) ? OR you want to set textview height according to text and font (dynamic height of call) ?

Comment: @AtulParmar I want to set font size according to textViewHeight. But of course textView height will change different screen size. For example if device is iPhone 8, textView height will be 137px and textSize 36pt. But if it is iPhone 8 Plus textView height and font size will be bigger. Actually this logic works but as I said I cannot set this size for initial when cell loaded. For this I have to swipe next cell and move backward.